# Run python process over SSH with ability to monitor process even after closing SSH connection and reconnecting

Tags: python, ubuntu, process, ssh, background-process

I am running a python process (through Django's manage.py) that will take about 6 days to complete. I would start it through an SSH tunnel, but that would require me to keep my Terminal window running and not let my computer fall asleep so the connection stays intact.

While the process is running, it reports the percentage on a single line (by replacing the line over and over again).

How can I start the process and be able to disconnect from SSH, but still be able to check on its progress when I reconnect?

Comment: I think if you start it as a daemon it will keep running even after your terminal exits

Comment: A simple solution is to use `screen`. Install `screen` on the system and `ssh` into it. Then run `screen`. Now that you're inside screen, start your program. Once it's started, use `C-A d` to detach, and you can close your connection. Later, `ssh` back in and use `screen -r` to reattach.

Comment: Thanks Waleed, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), your life will be so much more beautiful when you could load/reload your working session of terminals anytime you want --- they never die, and yet they ain't no zombies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Python question, rather an OS question.

So what you can do in `linux` is run your process with no hang up.

#### tmp.py

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

No you can run it like so:

```
sudo nohup python -u tmp.py >> output &
```

The output will be placed in this file.

Then you can watch the output comming to the file by doing

```
tail -f output
```